# How to check dropdown state of bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datetimepicker

I know the following checks the visibility of the entire widget but is there a way to check only the visibility/state of the dropdown calendar?

```
$("#datePicker").datetimepicker().is(":visible")
```

EDIT: the widget functions as expected and is contained in a modal with only format and positioning set.

```
$('#datePicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    widgetPositioning: {
        horizontal: 'auto',
        vertical: 'top'
    }
});
```

HTML when calendar dropdown is open/visible:

```
<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget dropdown-menu usetwentyfour top pull-right" style="display:block;">...</div>
<span class="input-group-addon toggleCalendar">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">...</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had inspected the code, you would easily had found a selector to target the dropdown.

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIF</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> next time ;)

Try with this :

```
console.log( "Dropdown visible: " + $(document).find(".datepicker-dropdown").is(":visible") );
```

Here is a demonstration in [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/dvKBaK).

---

**EDIT**

Previous was for Bootstrap DatePicker...
Here is the same answer for BootStrap DateTimePicker.

The answer is basically the same, only the selector to target the calendar differs.
In this case, this is `.dropdown-menu`.

```
console.log( "Dropdown visible: " + $(document).find(".dropdown-menu").is(":visible") );
```

Desmonstration in [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/dWdmgW).

Comment: querying the document using your statement returns `false` regardless, using the container or modal id as the selector returns `undefined`

Comment: I understand how to use inspector & your proposed solution but it simply doesn't work. I believe it is because the widget is contained within a modal. I wound up using a completely different approach but would still like to know how to query for the open state, see EDIT.

Comment: I edited. Using the inspector, this is the calendar selector you had to find.